# Mono zip from list of monos

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I started a new project with Springboot webflux with reactive programming. As a newbie I am still exploring Mono and Flux and how to use with Spring.

I have a userIdList which calls dao to get Mono object from DB and puts response in the list.

```
List<Mono<UserData>> list;
userIdList.foreach(id -> {
    list.add(userDao.findByUserId(id))
})
```

All I wanted to achieve is to pass this list as parameters to Mono.zip so that I will combine these monos and construct a response object.

```
Mono.zip(...List<Mono<UserData>>).flatMap(data->{
 data.getT1();
 data.getT2();
 return <your_response_object>;
});
```

Is there any better way to combine the individual mono responses and construct the response. Thanks in advance. As a newbie, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: how are you creating `List<Mono<UserData>>` You should not store multiple `Monos` in a list, if you have several `Monos` you merge them to a `Flux` don't store them in a list

Comment: Instead of List<Mono<T>> I would probably pick Flux<T> to tackle the problem. You can `reduce` all signals in the Flux to one Mono afterwards.

Comment: @Toerktumlare how do I add Mono's to Flux from the loop?

Comment: You change your dbcall to return a `Flux<User>` for a list of ids